# how do I use unix variable inside an HTML file

Tags: html, shell, unix, aix

Basic Idea:
I have an HTML which only has a table formed in it.

There are things like date, time, and result of some database queries.
I am mailing this detail in this table manually to people till now.

I have a script which calculates all the values required in this table. But I am not sure how do I append those values directly in the html file while executing the script.

Not sure how do I accomplish this, and whether it's possible.

P.S. I am sending mail with sendmail -t have tried sending trial HTML page and it's working fine. So the real issue is how do i append the variable values from the unix script into the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably have to provide place holders in the fixed html, then replace those with your value, using "sed".
e.g. test.html:

```
<html>
....
<div>The date is now %%DATE%%</div>
</html>
```

Then your script would replace %%DATE%%:

```
sed "s/%%DATE%%/$(date)/"  test.html
```

Similarly you can replace environment varables:

```
export MYDATE="2013-12-27"
sed "s/%%DATE%%/$MYDATE/" test.html
```

Comment: Tried and worked for me!!! thnks

Comment: Please mark the best answer using the check mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your HTML file into a template, adding markup that won't conflict with other content and then replace the markers with shell variables, for example given an HTML:

```
<html>
    <head><title>{{title}}</title></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Date</th></tr>
            <tr><td>{{name1}}</td><td>{{date1}}</td></tr>
            <tr><td>{{name2}}</td><td>{{date2}}</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

you could replace the values like this:

```
sed -e "s/{{title}}/Recent Stats/g" -e "s/{{date1}}/$(date)/g" -e "s/{{[^}]*}}/UNKNOWN/g" | sendmail
```

Another solution might be to construct the HTML to send by combining a header part + data part + footer part, like this:

```
{ cat header.html; ./script/that/dumps/data.sh; cat footer.html; } | sendmail
```

Comment: for replacing values, I tried sed in the way you have mentioned. I am good to go!! thnks :)